# What does this mean Y = {u : (∃z ∈ X) u ∈ z} = U {z: z ∈ X} = UX? I don't understand the property.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

What does this mean $Y = \{u : \exists z \in X (u \in z)\} = \bigcup\{z: z \in X\} = \bigcup X$? I don't understand the property. The issue is with $u ∈ z$.

Comment: Perhaps you should try some examples. For example, what is $\cup \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 5, 0\}, \{0\}\}$?

Comment: What "property"? I don't see anything, just the definition of union.

Comment: @azif00 the property is (∃z ∈ X) u ∈ z}.

Comment: @JackFrosher That means "there exists some $z$ which is an element of $X$, such that $u \in z$". What deeper meaning are you trying to extract from it?

Comment: @MarkSaving I understand that, but what does u∈z mean in this context.

Comment: @JackFrosher It means "$u$ is an element of $z$".

Comment: @MarkSaving Is z a set? Can you elaborate.

Comment: @JackFrosher $z$ is indeed a set. In fact, in set theory, absolutely everything is a set.

Comment: @MarkSaving  Seeing that z isn't capitalized, I'm assuming its a set of a single element? Am I wrong, if so, can you elaborate with an example.

Comment: @JackFrosher Sure. Consider $X = \{\{1\}\}$. Then $\cup X = \{1\}$. For suppose that $y \in \cup X$. Then there must exist some $z \in X$ such that $y \in z$. Then it must be the case that $z = \{1\}$, and it must be the case that $y = 1$. And we see that because $1 \in \{1\}$ and $\{1\} \in X$, $1 \in UX$. So therefore $\cup X = \{1\}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y$ is the set of elements that are elements in some element in set $X$. $$Y=\{ u : \exists z\in X~.u\in z\}$$

More simply: $Y$ is the union of sets within $X$. $$Y=\bigcup X = \bigcup \{z: z\in X\} $$

Should $X$ be $\{\{1\},\{2,4\},\{1,3,4\}\}$, then because there do exists sets within $X$ that contain the elements in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and no other, that set will be $Y$.  This is clearly the union of sets within this $X$.

---

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time.